# Como deixar imageView atras dos botoes?

Tags: android, xml

como o ramaral postou sete código:

No Layout da sua Activity tem de declarar uma ImageView

Se quiser que ela seja apenas visível após carregar num botão deverá incluir o atributo android:visibility="invisible"

`<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:src="@drawable/nomeDaSuaImagem" />`
No código da Activity, no onClick do botão, torne-a visível:

`Button button1;
ImageView imageView1;

imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE;
}
```

});`

eu gostaria de saber se tem como ela deixar escondidas atrás  dos botões .

Comment: Só usar um `FrameLayout`, que orienta a disposição das `Views` como se fosse uma pilha. Sobrepondo conforme a declaração.

Comment: Basta usar o `bringToFront` na `ImageView`. Em dispositivos anteriores ao 4.4 é necessário executar um `requestLayout` seguido de um `invalidate` depois.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para montar um layout com sobreposição no eixo Z basta usar o `FrameLayout`.

O `FrameLayout` desenha as `View's` empilhando as mesmas conforme a ordem em que foram declaradas.

Exemplo:

[image: Ordenação vertical]

Para trazer uma `View` para o topo, só usar o método: [`View.bringToFront`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#bringToFront()), que vai modificar a ordem das `View's` na lista que o pai mantém. Para dispositivos anteriores ao *KitKat* (4.4), basta chamar `requestLayout` e depois `invalidate` na própria `View`.

Referências: http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/thinking-like-web-designer.html