# Colocar uma seta no viewPager indicando para passar a foto

Tags: android

Estou usando este viewPager para fazer uma especie de galeria

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/galeria"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    />
```

estou querendo saber se tem como eu colocar está seta para indicar que tem mais fotos

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que as fotos veem em forma de lista de algum WebService, certo? Você pode simplesmente verificar o tamanho dessa lista e mostrar ou não o botão de next

Comment: e vou fazer isso

Comment: Ilgner, você teria que usar o FrameLayout com uma View por cima do ViewPager, da uma olhada nessa minha resposta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48356/como-deixar-imageview-atras-dos-botoes/48365#48365 pode te ajudar.