# Inserir barra de busca Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, algoritmo-de-busca, google-maps-android-api-2

Como inserir uma barra de busca no Google Maps no Android? Preciso de algo semelhante à imagem abaixo:

[image: Busca Google Maps]

Para este resultado, terei que usar Text e OverLay? Há algum exemplo para ajudar a entender?

Comment: Será que não é esse o efeito que quer obter? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48356/como-deixar-imageview-atras-dos-botoes/48365#48365

Comment: Sim, o efeito é este. Mas a dúvida é sobre a busca mesmo, não o layout. Estava procurando imaginando que a inserção de uma barra de search no Google Maps faria parte da API (como, por exemplo, quando se habilita o botão "MyLocation"). Já que não faz parte da API, como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa desenvolver sua própria barra. Existe uma opção semelhante disponível e que pode ser personalizada:

- [Using Search Widget](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget)
- [Locating User Input In Google Maps API](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/)

Lembrando que o objetivo da API é fornecer o acesso as **funcionalidades** do sistema, para que dessa forma não haja nenhuma importância a interface que a manipula. Exemplo disso é o retorno dessa busca: Apenas a longitude e latitude do local pesquisado, dados os quais você manipulará como desejar.

Comment: Testei aqui e era exatamente isso. Obrigado!